# How to add up values from a for looped textbox in JSP

Tags: jsp

Is there a way to add values from a textbox in a `for` loop? the following is part of the code in my jsp page

```
<% 
 DetailsMod bean = null;
 List resultList = (List) session.getAttribute("list");
 int count1=-1;
 String value2 = "";
 if(resultList.size() > 0 )  {  
  int rowNum = 1;
  for(int i=0; i<resultList.size(); i++){
     bean = (DetailsMod) resultList.get(i);
%>
<input type="text" name="tbx_cost" value="<%=bean.getCost()%>"/>

<% count1 = i;
}
}%>
```

Lets say the `resultList` returns 2 as value, then there will be 2 textboxes.
If user were to input 2000 in the first box and 3000 in the second box, is there a way for me to add these values up to 5000 and store it in a variable to pass it to another page?
Thanks in advance for any possible help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <% 
     DetailsMod bean = null;
     List resultList = (List) session.getAttribute("list");
     int count1=-1,totalCost=0;
     String value2 = "";
     if(resultList.size() > 0 )  {  
      int rowNum = 1;
      for(int i=0; i<resultList.size(); i++){
         bean = (DetailsMod) resultList.get(i);
         totalCost=totalCost+bean.getCost();
    %>
    <input type="text" name="tbx_cost" value="<%=bean.getCost()%>"/>

    <% count1 = i;
    }
    }%>
<input type="hidden" name="total_cost" value="<%=totalCost%>" />
```

Hope this helps. You may Alternatively also utilize javascript to add all cost inputs fields and set to other input hidden field.

----EDITED-----
change input elements as below

```
<input type="text" class="cost" name="tbx_cost" value="<%=bean.getCost()%>"/>
<input type="hidden" id="totalCost" name="total_cost" value="<%=totalCost%>" />
```

call below function on form-submit event.

```
<script>
function submitForm(){
var total=0;
jQuery('.cost').each(function(){total=total+jQuery(this).val();});
jQuery('#totalCost').val(total);

}
</script>
```

-----EDITED-----

Comment: Hi @PankajKathiriya thnk for the reply! this is great! bt is there a way to add the values from the textbox instead of the database? cause bean.getCost() wld be values from database and I would like to edit it once retrieved. Thnks

Comment: Hi @PankajKathiriya that didnt work either. now it gives values from the textbox bt the values are not added up.

Comment: I follow the above code accordingly only that instead of total and totalCost = 0 i changed it to double 0.0...with that i've got this error java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points so i did a system.out.println to find out the value of totalCost with input of 20000 for one box and 5000 for the other box and the outcome is 020000.0010000.00.00.0

Comment: I think i've got it already I just have to convert the string jQuery(this).val() to Number(jQuery(this).val()) 

Thnks for your help! :D